# Passing copy of a list to a function in python

Tags: python, list, function, copy

I'm trying to pass a copy of a list to a function in python so I can pop and append to a new list without losing the information in the old list.  But I'm having trouble.

here's my code

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print (magician.title())
        return magicians

def make_great(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        new_magician = magicians.pop()
        new_magicians.append(new_magician)
        print (new_magician.title() + ", is a great magician!!")
        return magicians

new_magicians = []
magicians = ['merlin', 'blaine', 'agaybi', 'copperfield']   
show_magicians(magicians)
make_great(magicians[:])
print ('\n' , magicians)
print ('\n' , new_magicians)
```

The second function is supposed to move the elements from the old list to the new and print the simple statement for each one without emptying the old list.  The problem is I get only 1 element printed and the same element is the only element moved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't assign the new list created by `make_great`, try `new_magicians = make_great(magicians[:])`.

Comment: @RobertR no, that's not the problem - the OP *explicitly* passes a shallow copy using the slice notation `[:]`. The problem is that that's unrelated to `new_magicians`!

Comment: Thank you for the edit Jon Sharpe.  This is my first question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe He's doing `new_magicians.append(...)` though.

Comment: Yes the lesson is about using a shallow copy when calling the function so the pop() works on the copy rather than the original.  How do I relate the shallow copy to `new_magicians' ?

Comment: @RobertR oh yeah! That's bonkers. OP: you seem deeply confused about parameters and state, you should either accept a list parameter or modify one in the outer scope (my preference would be the former) - having a mixture is asking for trouble. I would be inclined to have `make_great` take the original `magicians` and return **a completely new list** without actually modifying `magicians`, then you don't need to create `new_magicians` outside it.

Comment: Part of your problem is that `magicians.pop()` changes the list being iterated. After you remove the return statement, the for loop only runs twice. One the first loop it gets "merlin" and "copperfield" is removed from the list. On the second, it gets "blaine" and "agaybi" is poped from the list. On the third... well there is no third because you removed those items.

Comment: I don't know what you really want but it looks like you want to copy the list in reverse order. All you need is `new_magicians[:] = reversed(magicians)` if that is your intent.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning after the first magician is processed

Change the make_great function as follows

```
def make_great(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        new_magician = magicians.pop()
        new_magicians.append(new_magician)
        print (new_magician.title() + ", is a great magician!!")
    return magicians
```

Comment: Well it doesn't seem the return statement does anything because I hashtagged it and the same result happens.  Now I get the old list intact but only the last two elements moved to the new list!!!!

Comment: The old list is intact because you send a copy of it to your function, and the other problem is probably because you modify a list while iterating on it. Your code is very confusing, why one list is passed as parameter and not the other ?

Comment: This doesn't work because it is popping items from the list being enumerated.

Answer (score 1):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37972455/3001761) solves your immediate problem, but your code is still unnecessarily confusing, which I think contributed to your getting stuck.

The *"correct"* way to do this is to avoid mutating `magicians` within `make_great` at all. A Python function taking a mutable argument like this should *either* mutate its argument and return `None` *or* create a new object and return that. It should certainly not (for such a trivial task at least) mutate both its argument *and* an object in the enclosing scope *and* return that second object.

For example, you could have done:

```
def make_great(magicians):
    """Make each magician in the input great."""
    new_magicians = []  # create a brand new list
    for name in magicians:  # iterate over old list
        new_magicians.append(name + ' is a great magician!')  # add to new list
    return new_magicians  # note this is outside the for loop
```

Then you don't need to create `new_magicians` outside the function, or pass a copy of the original `magicians` to it:

```
magicians = ['merlin', 'blaine', 'agaybi', 'copperfield']   
new_magicians = make_great(magicians)
print(magicians)  # still the same
print(new_magicians)  # brand new list
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all thank you all so much.  I finally figured out the problem and how to solve it.  The exercise I'm working on specifically wants me to use the [:] to make a shallow copy of the list and pass it through a function to create a new list by popping.

The problem was I kept the `for` loop that prints the statement, inside the function instead of placing outside to be global.

Here's the new and correct code:

```
def show_magicians(magicians):
    for magician in magicians:
        print (magician.title())


def make_great(magicians):
    while magicians:
        new_magician = magicians.pop()
        new_magicians.append(new_magician)


new_magicians = []
magicians = ['merlin', 'blaine', 'agaybi', 'copperfield']
show_magicians(magicians)
make_great(magicians[:])

for magician in magicians:
    print ('\n' + magician.title() + " is a great magician!!")

print ('\n')
print (magicians)
print ('\n')
print (new_magicians)
```

Thanks again and sorry for the confusion.